# HTTPD with two different services in the same computer

Tags: apache, gitlab, httpd.conf

I have a CentOS 6.9 server that is running  a DokuWiki under HTTPD 2.2. This wiki is installed in `/var/www/html/dokuwiki`. Therefore, when you type `myserver.com/dokuwiki`, it enters the wiki. If you type `myserver.com`, a simple `index.html` file (`/var/www/html/index.html`) is shown with links to the Wiki and GitLab.

Now I have installed GitLab and configured it to also use HTTPD (by default it comes with NGINX integrated). Both GitLab and DokuWiki **are working correctly if I launch them by themselves**, but I cannot find the way to make them visible at the same time.

**What I would like is**: if the user types `myserver.com`, show the `index.html` with two links: one to the wiki (`myserver.com/dokuwiki`) and the other link to the GitLab server (`myserver.com/gitlab`). By clicking on each, the user can access the desired service.

What happens is that if put the configuration of gitlab with precedence over the other (by changing the name to `00-gitlab.conf`, for example), the configuration of the wiki doesn't work and when you type either `myserver.com` or `myserver.com/dokuwiki`, it doesn't find anything (
`Not found "/"` is shown) because it uses the other rules and there is no match (due to the `Location` directive of GitLab, I guess). GitLab works OK in this case.

If I put the configuration of the Wiki with precedence, I get a 404 error when I try to access `myserver.com/gitlab` because this rule is more general and therefore it ignores the other with the `Location` directive. The Index and the Wiki work OK in this case.

Here are the Virtual Hosts configurations for both, stored in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`. Everything is SSL and it is working OK. The configuration for HTTP (port 80) is virtually the same but I did not include it here. I also have `NameVirtualHost *:443` in `httpd.conf`.

Wiki/Root:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

GitLab

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver.com
  ServerSignature Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.key

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
  Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"

  <Location /gitlab>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://myserver.com/gitlab
  </Location>
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]
  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is both files have the same `ServerName` so which ever Apache reads first is the one that gets served. You'll want to combine the VirtualHost blocks and have a separate Location block where / servers your index.html, /dokuwiki severs your wiki, and /gitlab serves the ProxyPass

Comment: You are absolutely right. I fixed it, thanks. I posted my configuration that it is now working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I only need one VirtualHost and to correctly define my proxypass.

Here's the working file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"
    ServerSignature Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/myserver.com.key

    Alias /gitlab  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
    <Location /gitlab>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8181
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
        ProxyPassReverse http://myserver.com/gitlab
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
        RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
        ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  </Location>

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/myserver.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```